# Android: How to computing func(X) where x is a matrix?

Tags: android, math

I am trying to compute functions like sin(X), cos(X) where X is a matrix efficiently on Android. Any idea what library I can use? I have looked at org.apache.common.math3 but I cant figure out a way to do what I need. Help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is what I would like to do:

```
function Matrix process(Matrix X, Matrix Y) {
    Matrix result = SomeLib.add(SomeLib.sin(X), SomeLib.cos(Y), SomeLib.log(Y));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about android libraries, but in general you'd diagonalize your matrix, by computing its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and then perform the function on the diagonal elements.